# backref does not work on VS code

Tags: back-referencing, vscode, backref

I can't get back-referencing of citations to work with VS Code.

Here is my minimum reproducible example, which works fine on overleaf but not on VS Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{author_2018}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} 
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

where `test.bib` is:

```
@article{author_2018,
  title = {Title},
  author = {Example},
  year = {2018},
}
```

FYI, on VS Code I compile with `pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex ×2` and my latex-workshop settings.json are the following:

```
{
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
      "name": "pdflatex",
      "command": "pdflatex",
      "args": [
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "--aux-directory=build",
        "%DOC%"
      ],
      "env": {}
    },
    {
      "name": "bibtex",
      "command": "bibtex",
      "args": [
        "%DOCFILE%"
      ],
      "env": {}
    }
  ],
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
  {
      "name": "pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex`×2",
      "tools": [
        "pdflatex",
        "bibtex",
        "pdflatex",
        "pdflatex"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "latex-workshop.latex.autoClean.run": "onBuilt",
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "never",
  "latex-workshop.message.warning.show": false,
  "latex-workshop.message.error.show": false,
  "latex-workshop.view.pdf.invertMode.enabled": "compat",
  "latex-workshop.view.pdf.invertMode.grayscale": 0,
  "latex-workshop.view.pdf.invert": 1,
  "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "lastUsed",
  "latex-workshop.intellisense.biblatexJSON.replace": {
  
  },
  "latex-utilities.message.update.show": false
```

}

Comment: I am not sure whether `pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex×2` can work. But `latexmk` will yield an appropriate result as I have tested. So you can just use the default recipe provided by LaTeX-Workshop extension. (In command line, it is `latexmk -pdf`) As you have noticed, Overleaf uses LaTeXmk, so it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

@TeddyvanJerry's comment gave the solution: it works fine with `latexmk`.  (I wanted to reply to his comment but the text box is too small so I do it here).

To be precise, I had to remove the package `multibib`, which seems incompatible with `backref`.
Then, I compiled with `latexmk` after adding the following lines to `settings.json` > `latex-workshop.latex.tools`:

```
{
  "name": "latexmk",
  "command": "latexmk",
  "args": [
    "-synctex=1",
    "-interaction=nonstopmode",
    "-file-line-error",
    "-pdf",
    "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
    "%DOC%"
  ],
  "env": {}
}
```

and these ones into `settings.json` > `latex-workshop.latex.recipes`

```
  {
    "name": "latexmk",
    "tools": [
      "latexmk"
    ]
  },
```

Note that you don't have to add these lines if the `latexmk` option is already proposed for compilation (which it is by default). I needed to do that because I had modified `settings.json`. I prefer to use `pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex ×2` rather than `latexmk` because it is twice faster, but now I'll switch to `latexmk` when I need to compile the final version.

Comment: normally latexmk should be faster than `pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex ×2` because it only runs the necessary commands instead of doing all of them every time (maybe switch off your auto clean - this will destroy any time gain).